# nginx subdomain with different site than root

Tags: nginx, subdomain

I have the following configuration in my sites-available (with a symbolic link to enable):

```
#subdomain site
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name dokuwiki.[censored].org;

    root /var/www/html/dokuwiki;
    index index.php index.html;

    include /etc/nginx/templates/ssl.tmpl;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @dokuwiki;
    }

    location @dokuwiki {
        rewrite ^/_media/(.*) /lib/exe/fetch.php?media=$1 last;
        rewrite ^/_detail/(.*) /lib/exe/detail.php?media=$1 last;
        rewrite ^/_export/([^/]+)/(.*) /doku.php?do=export_$1&id=$2 last;
        rewrite ^/(.*) /doku.php?id=$1&$args last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        # Caution: be sure the php7.2-fpm.sock matches your version
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
    location ~ /(data|conf|bin|inc|vendor)/ {
      deny all;
    }
}
```

I want to have a different site at the site root:

```
#root site
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name [censored].org;

    root /var/www/html/site;
    index index.html;
}
```

The root site is just a dummy for now. When I try to load it, the browser tries to load the subdomain site, but issues a warning because the ssl certificate (which is set up for the subdomain) doesn't match.

Clearly I'm doing something wrong, but what?

Comment: hi, perhaps this config might be of interest https://serverfault.com/questions/655483/nginx-ssl-certificate-served-for-all-server-name-resolving-the-server-ip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try scaling back to a minimal configuration without SSL and ensure things work for 2 domains first:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;
  return 200 "example.com";
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name 1.example.com;
  return 200 "1.example.com";
}
```

```
$ curl http://example.com/
example.com

$ curl http://1.example.com/
1.example.com
```

---

Then, add SSL to an HTTPs endpoint to ensure that works:

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  ssl_certificate     example.com.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key example.com.key;

  server_name example.com;
  return 200 "example.com";
}
```

```
$ curl https://example.com/
example.com
```

Comment: Brilliant. Part of my ignorance that this exercise revealed was not knowing that I needed to explicitly forbid other subdomains someone might fancy to try other than the ones I've defined. Taking the whole thing apart helped me to see that. Thanks!